# How do i change the Cloud Shell Editor explorer to show Compute filesystem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-shell

I created a Compute instance with Ubuntu and would like to use it as a development environment, with the cloud shell editor as the IDE. I know how to ssh in the shell, but, the editor won't allow to browse the filesystem on the Compute instance. Please Help.

Comment: It seems that Cloud Shell is also spun up as a small virtual machine outside of any projects that may contain Compute Engines.  What this means is that the only way to access your Compute Engine would likely be through its public Internet facing interfaces (if any).  You might be able to NFS mount an NFS exported file system from the compute engine from which you could edit the files in Cloud Shell.

Comment: This is super complicated to do. I tried then stopped because i figured i ran the risk of wiping the FS

Comment: I tried to build a recipe of using NFS with Cloud Shell.  I was able to mount the Compute Engine share just fine but when I tried to create files or list files through the editor, what I found was that I could not.  Instead, the files were what was "under" the mount point of the file system.

Comment: Seems like cloud shell is nothing more than a teaser and easy way to utilize gcloud and gsutil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use a third-party tool for this. Cloud Shell does not have built-in support to browse external file systems.

Comment: Like Atom ? How do i do so with Atom ?

Comment: @NovaNova I don't use Atom, so I don't know.  By third-party I mean an SSH/SFTP tool. If Atom has built-in SSH, maybe.

Comment: Odd bit of work here. Can't seem to get angular previews when working that way.